# Point misplaced at street. Android application with maps.

Tags: android, gps, maps, location, city

I am developing an application that marks the path taken in real time (on android). Sometimes the gps fails and a point located in a building. Is there any way to fix this? Could I ask google if the marked point corresponds to a building, not the street, sending the location?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can only partially avoid that, by using the accuracy fields from location. you cannot rotally remove that effect, which is typical for GPS.
 It is possible to snap the position to the next road, when you have the vector data of the street (or map). But this is often not a good idea, when you travel by train then the losition will be false corrected to a near road. further if the street you are travelling dors nor exist on the map.